# How to fix React "Invalid hook call" error when importing npm link(ed) component that depends on styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

First, I added `react`, `react-dom` and `styled-components` to `peerDependencies` of npm link(ed) component (and removed these dependencies from `dependencies` and `devDependencies`).

Second, I used the [official](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#duplicate-react) workaround to use `npm link` (which, in theory, should solve this issue).

> This problem can also come up when you use `npm link` or an equivalent. In that case, your bundler might “see” two Reacts — one in application folder and one in your library folder. Assuming `myapp` and `mylib` are sibling folders, one possible fix is to run `npm link ../myapp/node_modules/react` from `mylib`. This should make the library use the application’s React copy.

I use the following scripts to link and unlink peer dependencies (I run them from directory of npm link(ed) component).

```
$ cat .env
PEER_DEPS_NODE_MODULES_PATH=/Users/sunknudsen/Code/sunknudsen/sunknudsen-website/node_modules

$ cat link-peer-deps.sh
#!/bin/sh

if [ -f .env ]
then
  export $(cat .env | sed 's/#.*//g' | xargs)
fi

npm link

npm link \
  $PEER_DEPS_NODE_MODULES_PATH/react \
  $PEER_DEPS_NODE_MODULES_PATH/react-dom \
  $PEER_DEPS_NODE_MODULES_PATH/styled-components

cd $PEER_DEPS_NODE_MODULES_PATH

npm link @sunknudsen/react-cms

printf "%s\n" "Done"

$ cat unlink-peer-deps.sh
#!/bin/sh

if [ -f .env ]
then
  export $(cat .env | sed 's/#.*//g' | xargs)
fi

npm uninstall

npm uninstall -g react react-dom styled-components

path="$PEER_DEPS_NODE_MODULES_PATH/@sunknudsen/react-cms"

if [[ -L "$path" ]]; then
  rm "$path"
fi

printf "%s\n" "Done"
```

The project that depends on npm link(ed) component does not appear to have `react`, `react-dom` or `styled-components` conflicts.

```
$ npm ls react            
sunknudsen-website@0.0.1 /Users/sunknudsen/Code/sunknudsen/sunknudsen-website
└── react@17.0.1

$ npm ls react-dom
sunknudsen-website@0.0.1 /Users/sunknudsen/Code/sunknudsen/sunknudsen-website
└── react-dom@17.0.1

$ npm ls styled-components
sunknudsen-website@0.0.1 /Users/sunknudsen/Code/sunknudsen/sunknudsen-website
└── styled-components@5.2.1
```

What am I missing? This issue is driving me bananas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991) is caused by `npm link` which uses symlinks.

A few solutions are suggested in the above issue.

1. Use a monorepo (I dislike this solution because I wish to maintain this in different repos)
2. Use [yalc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yalc) (I like this solution, but I am looking for a way for changes to bubble down to the main React project and trigger compilation and a browser reload)
3. Use [npm-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-sync) (full disclosure, I created this project to scratch my own itch).